# Most efficient way to display a grid of images

Tags: android, performance, android-canvas, android-gridview

What is the most efficient way to display a grid of random images on android?

I have a list of random album art images, I need to generate a grid out of them and use it as a background in my activity, the images are downloaded asynchronously, scaled down and cached, displaying them in a grid seems to consume a lot of RAM,(yes I'm recycling the bitmaps, and using LRU cache)

Would drawing them to a canvas be a better solution? Are there other efficient ways to do that?
Is the GridView safe, are there any guarantees that it won't run out of memory?

P.S. drawing them to a canvas would require me to redraw when the orientation or activity's size changes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t think there is a more efficient way, at least I can not think of one right now. What you could do, that depends if grid view is necessary, is using the Image carousel from Romain Guy which is made in Renderscript. I do not have the URL at the moment but it is a google-code project.

Another page where sometime are good stuff for those things is http://www.theultimateandroidlibrary.com/all

The LRUCache is really nice and fast and should do the trick. I also would be interested in a more efficient way.....